# When is a scope variable created in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular. Please, consider the following piece of code.

```
        <form name="newEventForm">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="eventName">Event Name:</label>
                <input id="eventName" required ng-model="event.name" type="text" placeholder="Name of your event...">


            <button ng-click="saveEvent(event, newEventForm)" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button ng-click="cancelEdit()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
        </form>
```

My question is - why do we need to pass the event argument to the saveEvent function? Doesn't using ng-model auto generate an event.name variable through two-way binding on the Angular side? e.g.

```
<form name="newEventForm">
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="eventName">Event Name:</label>
                    <input id="eventName" required ng-model="event.name" type="text" placeholder="Name of your event...">


                <button ng-click="saveEvent( newEventForm)" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                <button ng-click="cancelEdit()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
            </form>
```

In this second version of the code, I am not explicitly injecting event as a function parameter. However, when pressing submit, this is the code for saveEvent

```
$scope.saveEvent = function(newEventForm)
    {
        alert(1);
        alert(newEventForm.$valid);
        if(newEventForm.$valid)
        {
            window.alert('event ' + event.name + ' saved!');
        }
    }
```

and event is undefined. Shouldn't it be defined? Apologies if the question is a newbie's question. Just trying to get my head around how scope items are created through ng-model, and how does two-way binding work. Thanks !

*UPDATE*

Doh, I should've used $scope.event. Then it works. Thanks, like I said - new to this and it only dawned to me after I asked the question :)

Comment: don't use event as a global object but as a $scope object instead (in your controller): `$scope.event.name`

Comment: yes ! haha, I just figured it out myself. Many many thanks nevertheless :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is creating the event variable under the associated scope, use $scope.event.name. 
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Actually all variable or model which are specified in the html are `scope` variable.

**Example**

```
<div ng-controller="myController" ng-init="name='Hello World'">
    {{name}}
    <button ng-click="myFn(name)"> Click Me </button>
</div>
```

In this example, I have initiated a variable called `name`. It is actually a scope variable. This code will actually like

```
myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){
    $scope.name = "Hello World";

    $scope.myFn = function(param){
        // here you can see that your variable name passed from html is same as your scope variable
        if(param == $scope.name){
            alert("Yes, two are equal !!!");
        }
    }
});
```

This two are same. You can either use html or js.